# use getJSON to getData From WebMethod Highcharts Live Data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, highcharts, getjson

I ve this graph below that i would like insert data from a WebMethod (WebMethod is in a WebService):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container3',
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // ne marche pas dans les IE anciens
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function() {
            // MAJ du chart chaque seconde
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function() {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // temps
                    y = Math.random();
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'test'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function() {
            // generation de valeurs aléatoires

            var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;
            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
            data.push({
                x: time + i * 1000,
                y: Math.random()
            });
            }
            return data;
        })()
    }]
});
```

In the setInterval part, I d like to get value from a WebService WebMethod and put it in y,  :

WebService:[WebMethod]

```
public int getInt()
{
    val2 = rand.Next(1, 100);
    return val2;
}
```

Apparently I need to use GetJSON...
But I dont know how....
Could you help me giving an example please ?

Comment: But what your service returns ? json / xml  or somethinng different?

Comment: Hi , my WebMethod returns only an int val...

Comment: Please past your returned data.